# Черный экран после установки debian

Tags: linux, debian, установка

Решил установить *debian* себе на старый ноутбук (*packard bell model nav50*).
Установка началась хорошо, но я отошел попить воды, а когда вернулся, ноутбук был выключен.
*При попытке включить не происходит ничего, даже лого не показывает, в биос зайти соответственно тоже нельзя.*
**Есть ли шансы как-то это исправить? Если есть то как?**

- Когда ставил на виртуалку, все было ок.
- Я не застал вопрос о установке GRUB

Comment: Так может, ноутбук просто умер от старости?)

Comment: @andreymal, я не думаю что он мог так просто умереть от старости, т.к работал он очень хорошо. Глюков / тормозов не было, просто решил ось поменять.

Comment: @andreymal, я вижу вы очень активно следите за моей жизнью)